# The Result of Dividing 2 Power Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Is there a way to write a single series for the following division? $$\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{i}x^{i}}{\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j-2)a_{j}x^{j}}$$

Thanks, Radz.

Comment: Well, there will certainly _be_ a power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k x^k$. Note that your numerator will be the product of this power series and that of the denominator.

Comment: Dear @Semiclassical, Thanks. So, I just compare $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{l=0}^{k}b_{k}(l-2)a_{l-k}x^{k}$ (the mentioned product) to $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k}x^{k}$ (the numerator) to get the values of $b_{k}$?

Comment: Yes, though it will be tedious. (Though Ross's answer below makes me suspect there's a straighter route.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As told in answers and comments, a series exists but it is quite tedious to derive. Writing
$$\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{i}x^{i}}{\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j-2)a_{j}x^{j}}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_{i}x^{i}$$ the first coefficients are given by $$b_0=-\frac{1}{2}$$ $$b_1=-\frac{a_1}{4 a_0}$$ $$b_2=\frac{a_1^2-4 a_0 a_2}{8 a_0^2}$$ $$b_3=\frac{-a_1^3+4 a_0 a_2 a_1-12 a_0^2 a_3}{16 a_0^3}$$ $$b_4=\frac{a_1^4-4 a_0 a_2 a_1^2+8 a_0^2 a_3 a_1-32 a_0^3 a_4}{32 a_0^4}$$  $$b_5=\frac{-a_1^5+4 a_0 a_2 a_1^3-4 a_0^2 a_3 a_1^2+16 a_0^3 a_4 a_1-16 a_0^3
   a_2 a_3-80 a_0^4 a_5}{64 a_0^5}$$ in which a few patterns seem to appear.

Comment: Dear @Claude Leibovici, Thanks. I did derive these once Semiclassical suggested that a series exits.

Comment: @Radz. You are very welcome ! Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Note that $\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j-2)a_{j}x^{j}=(x\frac d{dx}-2)\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{i}x^{i}$

Comment: Dear @Ross Millikan, Does this mean I can cancel out $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{i}x_{i}$?

Comment: Not quite.  But *assuming the sum converges*, you can define $A(x)$ as that sum.  It then gives you a differential equation for the expression you want.

Comment: Dear @Ross Millikan, I still cannot figure how this approach works for finding $b_{k}$ in $\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{i}x^{i}}{\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(j-2)a_{j}x^{j}}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k x^k$.